# Is Go struct anonymous field public or private?

Tags: go, struct

As we know, fields start with capital letters are public, and those are not are private. But Golang also support anonymous field. For example:

```
type myType struct {
  string
}
```

These fields are design for [Embedding](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html). But is this field public or private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the typename of the embedded type is lower case, it has package visibility. For example:

```
type T struct {
    string
}

func main() {
    x := T{}
    x.string = "a"
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

However if you move type `T` to another package `p`:

```
package p

type T struct {
  string
}
```

```
package main

import "testmod/p"

func main() {
    x := p.T{}
    x.string = "a" // Error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the specification on [struct types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field. An embedded field must be specified as a type name T or as a pointer to a non-interface type name *T, and T itself may not be a pointer type. The unqualified type name acts as the field name.

The [unqualified name](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) of `string` is `string`.

From the specification on [exported identifiers](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> 1. the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode uppercase letter (Unicode character category Lu); and
> 2. the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.

The first character of `string` is not a Unicode uppercase letter.

It follows that the embedded field is not exported.  In other words, it's private to the package.